# select documents based on embedded document values in mongodb using linq

Tags: linq, mongodb-.net-driver

How can I select documents based on values within the embedded documents? For instance, I have class r that has a list of i classes. I want to select all r's that have i.name=="foo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select all `r`'s that have at least one `i` with `i.Name == "foo"` you can use this query:

```
var result = collectionOfRs.Where(r => r.ListOfIs.Any(i => i.Name == "foo"));
```

If you want to select all `r`'s that have **all** `i`'s with `i.Name == "foo"` you can use this one:

```
var result = collectionOfRs.Where(r => r.ListOfIs.All(i => i.Name == "foo"));
```